# How to insert multiple values in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to insert the data from 3 tables to combine some of the attributes from the 3 tables.

I have created a stored procedure, but I cannot execute this stored procedure. Any idea on this?

```
create procedure InsertMultiplevalue  
    (@startDate datetime,
     @endDate   datetime,
     @startTime datetime,
     @endTime   datetime,
     @quantity  int,
     @name      varchar(100),
     @type      varchar(200),
     @price     decimal(6,2) )  
as  
begin  
    insert into Attraction 
    values(@name)  

    declare @orgEmail varchar(50) 

    insert into TicketType 
    values(@quantity, @price, @type)  

    declare @ticketID int  
    insert into ItemBooking 
    values(@startDate, @startTime, @endDate, @endTime)  

    declare @ItemBookingID int = @@identity
end
```

I get this error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertMultiplevalue, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Have you checked, if the column name and the number of supplied values match the table definition?

Comment: What are the tables structure? Any DDL would help.

Comment: That's one of the **compelling reasons** why you should **ALWAYS** define the list of columns in your `INSERT INTO ....` statement!

Comment: 1. specify columns in INSERT statements
2. do not use @@identity global variable, use SCOPE_IDENTITY(), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your insert statements "values" match the tables that will insert to. Otherwise you might be trying to insert too much or very little values.
I would recommend to first look how the tables are defined just then, prepare the insert statements

Answer (score -1):

While inserting into table, you have to insert all column values if you are not supposed to give column names there excluding identity column like

```
insert into Attraction 
     (
        column names here
        Not null column names must be mandatory to insert data to table
     )
select
      column name values
```

Comment: That is not valid tsql. And do not assume that "primary key" and "identity column" are synonyms for each other. And default constraints also have a role in this issue.